# hibernate + spring boot store date on UTC time zone troubles

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, datetime, spring-boot

I'm making some tests to define UTC as default time zone for my application. First of all I want my datetime values to be stored with the UTC one.

According to VLAD MIHALCEA (https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-store-date-time-and-timestamps-in-utc-time-zone-with-jdbc-and-hibernate/) and https://moelholm.com/2016/11/09/spring-boot-controlling-timezones-with-hibernate/ I have set in my properties file:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone= UTC
```

For testing I'm using h2 database, I've created a sample entity with all java 8 dateTime Type.

In my liquibase config they are defined like this:

```
<column name="instant" type="timestamp"/>
<column name="local_date" type="date"/>
<column name="local_time" type="time"/>
<column name="offset_time" type="time"/>
<column name="local_date_time" type="timestamp"/>
<column name="offset_date_time" type="timestamp"/>
<column name="zoned_date_time" type="timestamp"/>
```

I think I'm using the good type for every fields. It's work for all fields except for "local_time" "offset_time" which are Time sql types not timestamp.

[image]

As you can see i added this row at 8:39am (Paris GMT+2) and timestamps have the good UTC value (6:38am).
BUT both "local_time" and "offset_time" have a strange value (7:39am).

I wonder why this behaviour, if some of you have an idea why my two time fields not store values correctly.

PS: version:

- Hibernate: 5.2.17.Final
- Spring boot: 2.0.4.RELEASE

My sample Entity use to insert data :

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.*;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Table(name = "avdev_myData")
public class MyData implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "instant")
    private Instant instant;

    @Column(name = "local_date")
    private LocalDate localDate;

    @Column(name = "local_time")
    private LocalTime localTime;

    @Column(name = "offset_time")
    private OffsetTime offsetTime;

    @Column(name = "local_date_time")
    private LocalDateTime localDateTime;

    @Column(name = "offset_date_time")
    private OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime;

    @Column(name = "zoned_date_time")
    private ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime;
```

Comment: `jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone= UTC` must be `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone= UTC`. Else it won't be mapped. Also HOW are you inserting that data?

Comment: my bad. i have "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone" set correctly.
I insert my data with a rest call and a spring data reporitory using a "MyData" entity

Comment: Please fix the property and add some code and explain which types you are using (Joda Time or JDK8).

Comment: you're right i have to add my entity to be more clearer. As i said at the begining of the post i only use JDK8 Time API.

I want to test with all JDK8 types to be sur they will be handle properly with the UTC config option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened an issue in the hibernate bug tracker and had an answer of my problem.

For LocalTime the tranformation is relative to the 1st january 1970 not the day i had run the test. So the DST is not handled.

According to Vlad Mihalcea we have to use LocalDateTime instead because we know the date and of course if it's on DST period or not.

there is the whole response here:
[https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12988?focusedCommentId=103750&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-103750](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12988?focusedCommentId=103750&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-103750])

regards

Answer (score 8):

Have a try:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class YourApplication {

    @PostConstruct
    void started() {
        // set JVM timezone as UTC
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution work but according to : https://moelholm.com/2016/11/09/spring-boot-controlling-timezones-with-hibernate/

"This solution works. But it is very invasive and has a few potential drawbacks[...]"

that's why i prefer the hibernate tuning solution.

Comment: wouldn't be better approuch to use  org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean     or      even       org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent;
 org.springframework.context.event.EventListener;      since are based on spring framework ?

Comment: Thanks you saved my bacon. For some reason my integration test, although having the UTC setting for the hibernate config, was not configured as such. I added your fix to the test, and it aligned the time of the DATETIME retrieved. No idea why this is happening in Intellij, when i package the application into a jar and run it, all date comparisons work fine!

Answer (score 2):

In case decide using MySQL in my case works properly with

> spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect =
>   org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57InnoDBDialect
>
> spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://DBHOST:3306/DBNAME?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC

Comment: Is it working with "time" sql columns ? Because it's my problem. I'll test with mysql but with both h2 and postgres it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://...?serverTimezone=Asia/Shanghai
```

works for me.

1. Hibernate SHOULD reflect mysql timezone.
2. mysql jdbc should reflect mysql timezone.

Answer (score 0):

Once the spring context is initialized ....

```
import org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent;
import org.springframework.context.event.EventListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


@Component
public class ApplicationStartUp {

    @EventListener(ContextRefreshedEvent.class)
    public void contextRefreshedEvent() {

        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

    }   

}
```

OR

```
@Component
public class InitializingContextBean implements InitializingBean {

    private static final Logger LOG  = Logger.getLogger(InitializingContextBean.class);

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {         
            TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    }
}
```

Comment: I suppose that doing this, you loose nice features, like converting from system default timezone to UTC. 
Then everytime you will need to tell which timezone has the LocalDateTime that you are converting to UTC

Answer (score 0):

Setting the default timezone as UTC didn't resolve my problem completely. It brought another problem, when I recorded an entity with OffsetTime property, it swallowed the offset info and data saved data in wrong way. For example, 18:25+03:00 turns into 18:25+00:00. I think this is the worst scenario, because data becomes corrupted.

To overcome this issue and not lose offset info, I used withOffsetSameInstant method of the OffsetTime class and record my entity like that.

```
ZoneOffset systemZoneOffset = ZoneId.systemDefault().getRules().getOffset(Instant.now());
OffsetTime offsetTime = clientOffsetTime.withOffsetSameInstant(systemZoneOffset);
```

Lastly, this will work for any timezone that your computer is using. This should also work for OffsetDateTime type of properties.